# Test Cmake run finished with errors (CLION)

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, clion

I have the following problem after changing path to one that is easier for the operating system.  My MinGW configuration in CLion:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2018.2.5/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler
"C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: C:/Users/MichaĹ‚/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_da460/fast"
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_da460.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_da460.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Michaâ”‚/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_da460.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_da460.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c C:\Users\Michaâ”ĽĂ©\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment\_build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Michaâ”ĽĂ©\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment\_build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\cmTC_da460.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_da460.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_da460.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Michaâ”‚/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'cmTC_da460/fast' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_da460/fast] Error 2




CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/MichaĹ‚/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/MichaĹ‚/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Error code: 1
```

Here is a screenshot from my PC:

Comment: This is a tough filepath for gcc to follow:  "C:\Users\Michaâ”ĽĂ©..."   Can you go back and try to compile a test program yourself using mingw-32/gcc?  ie., create a hello world and see if you can compile it from the command line.

Comment: I can compile and run sipmly hello world program from the command line. Look now at the queston, because i changed filepath but it didn't help.

Comment: These two lines bother me:      C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_da460.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c C:\Users\Michaâ”ĽĂ©\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment\_build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
gcc.exe: error: 
  
  C:\Users\Michaâ”ĽĂ©\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment\_build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c: No such file or directory
  Each of these lines has a double quotation mark character -"-.  My compiler cannot handle this in a code path.  It may be that a character is being translated incorrectly from your locale to mine.

Comment: I have seen this before as well -- where cmake complains that it is not able to compile a simple program.  If your output is now different, please modify the question to show the new output.  Thank you.

Comment: I think you were right that there was a problem with double quotation mark character. I created my windows account with my national language charchter "ł" and since  i have changed Michał into Michal evrything is  ok and there is no problem with toolchains configuration, so thank you very much for helping me with this problem .

Comment: Great!  I installed Mingw on my windows box and configured it with CLion for the first time.  It took some effort, but it finally came together.  Give Kudos all around.

Comment: Please give upvotes to those who helped with your prior question to provide incentive to try to investigate further.